# Why can't I add a class that was extended from SimplePanel to the RootPanel?

Tags: gwt

I'm designing a simple application in GWT and have different views in the client side. Each view is extended from SimplePanel and will be added to the RootPanel as needed.

My first view is the Login class:

```
public class Login extends SimplePanel
{
    private final TextBox txt_login;
    private final PasswordTextBox txt_password;
    private final Button btn_login;
    private final Grid main_grid;

    Login()
    {
        super();

        txt_login=new TextBox();
        txt_password=new PasswordTextBox();
        btn_login=new Button("Login");
        main_grid=new Grid(3,2); 

        main_grid.setWidget(0, 0, new HTML("Login"));
        main_grid.setWidget(1, 0, new HTML("Password"));
        main_grid.setWidget(0, 1, txt_login);
        main_grid.setWidget(1, 1, txt_password);
        main_grid.setWidget(2, 1, btn_login);

        setWidget(main_grid);
    }
}
```

And I try to add it to the RootPanel in my entry point class with the following code:

```
Login login_box=new Login();
RootPanel.get().add(login_box);
```

But I end up getting the following error in runtime:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:345)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget.java:475)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.adopt(Panel.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:97)
    at de.enercon.epi.client.Epi.onModuleLoad(Epi.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:405)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Curiously I'm perfectly able to get it working if I extend the Login class from DialogBox instead of the SimplePanel.

What could be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but I would suggest extending `Composite` instead of `SimplePanel`, and then the problem should just go away and you'll be following best practices :-) http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/05/widget-best-practices-widget-building.html

```
public class Login extends Composite {
  private final TextBox txt_login;
  private final PasswordTextBox txt_password;
  private final Button btn_login;
  private final Grid main_grid;

  Login() {
    txt_login = new TextBox();
    txt_password = new PasswordTextBox();
    btn_login = new Button("Login");
    main_grid = new Grid(3, 2);

    main_grid.setWidget(0, 0, new HTML("Login"));
    main_grid.setWidget(1, 0, new HTML("Password"));
    main_grid.setWidget(0, 1, txt_login);
    main_grid.setWidget(1, 1, txt_password);
    main_grid.setWidget(2, 1, btn_login);

    initWidget(main_grid);
  }
}
```

Comment: "The composite is useful for creating a single widget out of an aggregate of multiple other widgets contained in a single panel."


Great! It works and is exactly what I need :D

Answer (score 2):

Simple panel may only accept one child widget. You cannot extend it to include multiple widgets.

The best practice is to add a Composite or LayoutPanel to the RootPanel - this is your "app" and you can size and style it as you want your app to look. Then you extend Composite to create your "views", and you remove and add your views to the "app" as a user navigates your app.

Comment: Doesn't the `SimplePanel` have only one child widget, the `Grid`?